# Writing out a binary structure to file, unexpected results?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write out a packed data structure to a binary file, however as you can see from `od -x` below the results are not expected in their ordering.  I'm using gcc on a 64-bit Intel system.  Does anyone know why the ordering is wrong?  It doesn't look like an endianness issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct B {
     char a;
     int b;
     char c;
     short d;
} __attribute__ ((packed));

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     FILE *fp;
     fp = fopen("temp.bin", "w");

     struct B b = {'a', 0xA5A5, 'b', 0xFF};

     if (fwrite(&b, sizeof(b), 1, fp) != 1)
          printf("Error fwrite\n");

     exit(0);
}
```

ASCII 61 is `'a'`, so the `b.a` member.  ASCII 62 is `'b'`, so the `b.c` member.  It's odd how `0xA5A5` is spread out over the sequence.

```
$ od -x temp.bin 
0000000 a561 00a5 6200 00ff
0000010
```

Comment: It's just endianness. You need to read the bytes `a561 00a5` -> `00a5 a561` and same for the second set.

Comment: Dump to stdout as *bytes*, not as 16-bit unsigned values.

Comment: I think you've got an Endianness issue going on here.  Try running `od -t xC`.

Comment: It's the output format of `od` [grouped as 16 bit ints with endianness]. Try `od -A x -t x1z -v temp.bin` to get `000000 61 a5 a5 00 00 62 ff 00                          >a....b..< 000008`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`od -x` groups the input into 2-byte units and swaps their endianness. It's a confusing output format. Use `-t x1` to leave the bytes alone.

```
$ od -t x1 temp.bin
0000000 61 a5 a5 00 00 62 ff 00
0000010
```

Or, easier to remember, use `hd` (hex dump) instead of `od` (octal dump). `hd`'s default format doesn't need adjusting, plus it shows both a hex and ASCII dump.

```
$ hd temp.bin
00000000  61 a5 a5 00 00 62 ff 00                           |a....b..|
00000008
```

Comment: "od" does not swap endianness, it just seems so on those systems with little endian coding. Actually it does not swap, it reads 2 bytes for a 16-bit value and shows it. This is one main disadvantage of little endian coding.

Answer (score 2):

`od -x` writes out two little-endian bytes. Per [the `od` man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html):

```
-x     same as -t x2, select hexadecimal 2-byte units
```

So

```
0000000 a561 00a5 6200 00ff
```

is, on disk:

```
0000000 61a5 a500 0062 ff00
```